# ListView Android with Array database

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview, baseadapter

I'm having one problem in show my ListView correctly

If I declare

```
String[] cod = {"cod1","cod2", "cod3"};
String[] desc = {"desc1","desc2", "desc3"};
String[] preco = {"1.00","2.00", "3.00"};
```

My adapter is:

```
lista = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
lista.setAdapter(new dataListAdapter(cod, desc, preco));
```

It works perfectly!

[image]

But if I get the data from a database, the ListView shows only one row.

```
results = DbHelper.getItemsDao().queryRaw(sqlGetItems);

/*GET ALL RESULTS FROM DATABASE*/
List<String[]> array = results.getResults();    

int count = array.size();

String[] cod = null, desc = null, preco = new String[count];

for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    String[] res = array.get(i);
    cod = new String[]{res[0]} ;
    desc = new String[]{res[1]};
    preco = new String[]{res[3]};
}

lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
lista.setAdapter(new dataListAdapter(cod, desc, preco));
```

[image]

Comment: ru sure data is correct in db?

Comment: No, the sql returns correctly 3 registers

Comment: post complete adapter class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the code carefully:

```
        for(int i = 0; i<count; i++){
            String[] res = array.get(i);

             cod = new String[]{res[0]} ;
             desc = new String[]{res[1]};
             preco = new String[]{res[3]} ;
        }
        lista=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        lista.setAdapter(new dataListAdapter(cod, desc, preco));
```

Here, the varables `cod`, `desc` and `preco` are created every time in the loop. So they are the last one at the end. 
You can try like as follows:

```
    String[] cod = new String[count];
    String[] desc = new String[count];
    String[] preco = new String[count];
    for(int i = 0; i<count; i++){
       String[] res = array.get(i);

       cod[i] = res[0] ;
       desc[i] = res[1];
       preco[i] = res[3] ;
    }
```

Comment: I Understand. What is the correct way to create the array in the loop?

Comment: That's my pleasure :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:

```
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    String[] res = array.get(i);
    cod.add(res[0]) ;
    desc.add(res[1]);
    preco.add(res[3]);
}
```